# onclick="func(); return false;" doesn't work when using $.get()

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

Consider a part of a web page:

```
<script>
function fun() {
    alert("Link won't work");
}
</script>
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="fun(); return false;">link</a>
```

This works as is desired. But adding jquery `$.get()` command makes it fail:

```
<script>
function fun() {
    $.get("http://yahoo.com");
}
</script>
<a href="http://google.com" onclick="fun(); return false;">link</a>
```

Why is so? In general, in js I want to process `href` of `<a />` element and use `$.get()` function to grab some data and then display it using other jquery functions. I still want `<a />` to have `href` attribute.

Here in the example two external addresses are used but in my case I want to send requests within the same domain. By "failing" I mean that link will get me to the `href` address.

Comment: "fail" how? What happens? You are aware that calling `get` like that doesn't do anything?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the A in AJAX is for asynchronous: called like that, "return false" would be called while the AJAX request is still processing, not after it was executed.

Comment: The code as quoted works just fine: http://jsbin.com/azosi3 The problem lies outside the quoted code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your problem description, I suspect you have a javascript error that is causing the code to not be executed at all.  @Darin's should solve your problem unless the javascript error is elsewhere.  In a situation like this I would use Firefox/Firebug and look at the console output to see if and where the error is.

Answer (score 3):

[`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is used to send an AJAX request. Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you cannot send an AJAX request to a different domain. So unless your site is hosted on `yahoo.com`, `$.get("http://yahoo.com");` will always fail. Also if you was using jquery your code would probably more look like:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
$(function() {
    $('#link').click(function() {
        $.get('/somepage_on_your_server', function(result) {
            // Handle the result of the AJAX call
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<a href="http://google.com" id="link">link</a>
```

Comment: Even if it doesn't fail, it doesn't do anything meaningful either, because no callback is given.